# Akka-zeromq socket/actor won't receive messages

Tags: scala, akka, zeromq, akka-zeromq

## Questuion

I'm trying to implement a simple actor that will receive messages from zeromq using akka-zeromq.

```
import akka.actor._
import akka.zeromq._

class PullActor extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case x => println("M: " + x.toString)
  }
}

object Main extends App {
  val system = ActorSystem("system")

  val pullActor = system.actorOf(Props[PullActor], "pull-actor")

  val pullSocket = ZeroMQExtension(system).newSocket(
    SocketType.Pull, Listener(pullActor), Connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:8008"))

  println("Press ENTER to exit")
  Console.readLine()
  system.shutdown()
}
```

The system prints just

```
M: Connecting
```

---

## Additional information

Sending messages is done via a simple python

```
import zmq
ctx = zmq.Context()
p = ctx.socket(zmq.PUSH)
p.bind("tcp://*:8008")
p.send("test")
```

The other strange thing I noticed is that ever after pressing enter the program will not terminate. It will if I send it a message using the python script. Here is the full output:

```
[DEBUG] [12/04/2012 18:01:45.175] [main] [EventStream(akka://system)] logger log1-Logging$DefaultLogger started
[DEBUG] [12/04/2012 18:01:45.178] [main] [EventStream(akka://system)] Default Loggers started
Press ENTER to exit
M: Connecting

[DEBUG] [12/04/2012 18:01:54.176] [system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [EventStream] shutting down: StandardOutLogger started
[DEBUG] [12/04/2012 18:01:54.176] [system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [EventStream] shutting down: StandardOutLogger started
[DEBUG] [12/04/2012 18:01:54.179] [system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [EventStream] all default loggers stopped
```

Using

```
scalaVersion := "2.10.0-RC3"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.1.0-RC3" cross CrossVersion.full,
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-zeromq" % "2.1.0-RC3" cross CrossVersion.full,
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-slf4j" % "2.1.0-RC3" cross CrossVersion.full
)
```

`libzmq` is version `3.2.2` (on Arch Linux)

This is the `application.conf`

```
akka {
  loglevel = DEBUG
  zeromq {
    socket-dispatcher {
      executor = thread-pool-executor
      type = "PinnedDispatcher"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: FYI - it works for me - the PULL socket receives the message.  Sorry. Might want to try adding a sleep (say 1 second) before and after the python send.  You may have a race condition where you bind and send before the actor gets a chance to connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found the issue. It's the libzmq library version. Downgrading the library to 2.2 works. I've created a ticket for the Akka team: https://www.assembla.com/spaces/akka/tickets/2769-akka-zeromq-doesn-t-receive-messages-with-libzmq-3-2#/activity/ticket:

Comment: libzmq's api changed considerably between versions 2.x and the more recent 3.x releases - with the effect of breaking existing clients of libzmq. Notably, pubsub filtering is now done at the publisher side instead of subscriber side. More information on these changes are located [here](http://www.zeromq.org/docs:3-1-upgrade).

Comment: I had the same issue. By building ZeroMQ 2.2 from source the problem is solved. It turned out that the 'ffi-rzmq' gem in Ruby will break due to the downgrade, simply use the 'zmq' gem instead.